# Apache VirtualHost, multiple ServerName in one line

Tags: apache, virtualhost, server-name

I am using the following tag

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>

    ServerName blog.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias blog
```

to create a virtual host. I've put the ServerName as my subdomain which is blog. However, i'm trying to figure out a way to add www.blog. aswell in the same line rather than having to create a completely new virtual host.

Is there a way for this to be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sure, you can add multiple entries to the `ServerAlias`, see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias

Comment: I tried that before posting, but it didnt work. But I tried: ServerAlias blog www.blog, also tried: ServerAlias blog www that also did not work, then tried ServerAlias blog www.blog.mydomain.com and this worked.

Answer (score 17):

Apache allows multiple server Aliases

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     
     ...

     ServerName blog.mydomain.com
     ServerAlias www.blog.com
     ServerAlias blog
     ServerAlias add-as-many-as-you-want

     ...
    
</VirtualHost>
```

The Above can also be achieved as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     
     ...

     ServerName blog.mydomain.com
     ServerAlias www.blog.com blog add-as-many-as-you-want

     ...
    
</VirtualHost>
```

So you can choose what you want from the two.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#serveralias There's no comma between aliases